# Firebaseui buttons in React are too big

Tags: html, css, reactjs, firebase, firebaseui

I want to show some firebaseui Login button on the screen with this React code:

```
import 'firebase/compat/auth'
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'

// Environment variables
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.APP_ID,
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const auth = firebase.auth()

export const Firebase = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<firebase.User | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const ui = firebaseui.auth.AuthUI.getInstance() || new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(auth)

    ui.start('.firebase-auth-container', {
      signInFlow: 'popup',
      signInOptions: [
        {
          provider: firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        },
      ],
      signInSuccessUrl: '/page-router',
    })
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((firebaseUser) => {
      setUser(firebaseUser)
    })

    return unsubscribe
  }, [])

  console.log('user', user)

  return <div className="firebase-auth-container"></div>
}
```

I got this result:
[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

Any idea, what causes this? I don't know, what other parts of the application can effect the login button.

Comment: Please edit the question to show how you integrated Auth UI into your app. We should be able to duplicate what you've done and see that you are getting all of the CSS correctly that styles the UI.

Comment: @DougStevenson, I think I added all connecting code. Can other parts be important too?

Comment: Yes, anything could be injecting CSS that overrides the correct styles.  That's why it's important to show a [complete minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that's easy for everyone to understand everything that's going on.  Anything that we can't see could be a problem.

Comment: Bah, I forgot to import css... Solution was: `import 'firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css'`